# Discord.js - Getting additional Text from Slash Command

Tags: discord.js

When writing a Discord.js [Slash Command](https://discordjs.guide/interactions/slash-commands.html#options), is it possible to get the text that was entered "outside" of the defined options?

Let's say I have the following SlashCommand defined:

```
new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('slashtest')
        .addStringOption(option => option.setName('name').setDescription('Test Option').setRequired(true))
        .addStringOption(option => option.setName('text').setDescription('Second Option').setRequired(true)),
```

In this example I would like to get the text "Even more Stuff"
[image: Example Image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [discord.js documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/CommandInteraction) and the [discord developer documentation](https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/receiving-and-responding#interaction-object-interaction-data-structure), you can only get user input from the command options in the discord slash command 'handler' (the menu that pops up when you enter '/').

From my past experience of using slash commands, I don't believe it's possible to retrieve user input outside of options. I guess you could create more options for more specific user input.